# Ansible Community Edition - Error "failed to find required executable at in path /sbin/"

Tags: plugins, ansible, at-command

I am using Ansible Community Edition on CentOS 7.

I wanted to run commands periodically and using `at` plugin which is part of [ansible.posix.collection](https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.posix).

When I refer in playbooks like

```yaml
- name: check size of disk
  ansible.posix.at:
    ...
```

*... not giving the full script here*

It gives an error "Failed to find required executable at in path".

Can someone suggest here? I do not know how to point `at` plugin which is not part of ansible-core to `$PATH`, if that solves the issue.

Comment: I guess you are running an `ansible-playbook` command in a crontab then? Mind that crontab, per default, uses a restricted environment. You can add sensible information in the `$PATH` for that cron though. Interesting read: https://serverfault.com/a/449652

Comment: Most probably, the `at` command is in `/usr/bin` or similar but, as raised by your error, your path only contains `/sbin/`

Answer (score 0):

This is because the program **at** should be installed on the managed machine and available under one of the paths in the $PATH variable.

See the section "Requirements" here : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/at_module.html#id2